# Write "java -version" to a file using ant

Tags: ant

I want to have a target in my script that records the user's java version in a file format. But for some reason the output to the command "java -version" cannot be recorded.

I tried running `java -version > java.txt` in terminal, which doesn't work either so I am guessing the result from java -version cannot be captured?

Comment: Try `java -version &> version.txt`.

Comment: Thanks @Carl, I realized the output is in the error stream so I just captured that through ant instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following `exec` task in your Ant `build.xml`:

```
<exec executable="java">
    <arg value="-version"/>
    <redirector output="java-version.txt" alwayslog="true"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using sshexec as I am logging a remote machine and I just captured the error stream as that task doesn't seem to have a redirector. But your method should work for general case.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use Ant builtin properties, see [Ant Manual](https://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) / Built-in Properties, f.e. :

```
<echoproperties prefix="java"/>
```

will print all Java properties.
There are 3 version related properties :

1. java.version
2. java.vm.specification.version
3. java.vm.version

So simply take the appropriate property:

```
<project>

 <echo>
  ${java.version}
  ${java.vm.specification.version}
  ${java.vm.version}
 </echo>

 <!-- assuming you want ${java.version} -->
 <echo file="foobar.txt">Java Version = ${java.version}</echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo]   1.7.0_72
[echo]   1.7
[echo]   24.72-b04
```